# confusing useEffect situation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, zustand

Apologies if this is a long post. I have been trying to make sense of this for the past few days and yet I have not been able to. I would appreciate any help. Below, in my main component, I have a series of questions. The answer to each is a simple yes or no (initialized as null) that will be saved by Zustand. When the user goes to the next question, I am keeping the previous answers since the fields are controlled. However, if the user clicks the Back button in `<PageNav/>` on any card, I want to reset that specific card's answer back to null. My intuition in the custom hook was to reset to null using the `return` cleanup function of the `useEffect` as you see below. However, it is not working.

**Main component:**

```
export default const Test = () => {

  const questions: Record<number, ReactElement> = {
    1: <Question1 />,
    2: <Question2 />,
    3: <Question3 />,
    4: <Question4 />,
    5: <Question5 />,
      };

  // Set the page navigation state
  useEffect(() => {
    nav.setTotalPages(Object.keys(display).length);
    return () => {
    nav.setTotalPages(0);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {display[nav.page]}
      <PageNav />
    </>
  );
};
```

**Here is the question component:**

```
export default const Question1 = () => {
  const { value, handleChange } = useQuiz("question1");

  return (
    <RadioYesNo
      question="Question 1"
      lable={[
        "Yes",
        "No",
      ]}
      value={value}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};
```

**Custom component for each question:**

```html
export default const RadioYesNo = ({
      question,
      lable,
      value,
      handleChange,
    }) => {
      return (
        <Stack spacing={4} alignItems="center">
          <Typography>{question}</Typography>
          <RadioGroup name="question" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
            <FormControlLabel value="y" control={<Radio />} label={lable[0]} />
            <FormControlLabel value="n" control={<Radio />} label={lable[1]} />
          </RadioGroup>
        </Stack>
      );
    };
```

**Custom hook to implement the useEffect for each question:**

```
export default const useQuiz = (storeProperty: keyof EligibilitySlice) => {
  // Page navigation states:
  const resetPageState = useStore.use.resetPageState();
  const isNextClicked = useStore.use.isNextClicked();
  const isBackClicked = useStore.use.isBackClicked();

  const storeValue = useStore.use[storeProperty]();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(
    storeValue === "y" ? "y" : storeValue === "n" ? "n" : ""
  );

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    resetPageState(); // Resets isBackClicked & isNextClicked to false
    console.log("page state is reset");
    useStore.setState({
      [storeProperty]: value === "y" ? "y" : value === "n" ? "n" : null,
    });

    useStore.setState({ isNextActive: !!value });

    return () => {
      console.log("unmounting");
      if (isBackClicked) {
        useStore.setState({
          [storeProperty]: null,
        });
        console.log("property ", storeProperty, " was reset to null");
      }
      useStore.setState({ isNextActive: false });
    };
  }, [value, isBackClicked, isNextClicked]);

  return { value, handleChange };
};
```

**and here is the PageNav component that houses the Next and Back buttons, which update the isBackClicked and isNextClicked states in Zustand store:**

```
const PageNav = () => {
  const nav = {
    page: useStore.use.page(),
    totalPages: useStore.use.totalPages(),
    prevPage: useStore.use.prevPage(),
    nextPage: useStore.use.nextPage(),
    isBackActive: useStore.use.isBackActive(),
    isNextActive: useStore.use.isNextActive(),
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={4} alignItems="center">
      <Typography px={6}>{`${nav.page} of ${nav.totalPages}`}</Typography>
      <Stack direction="row" spacing={4}>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => {
            nav.prevPage();
          }}
          disabled={nav.page === 1 || !nav.isBackActive}
        >
          Back
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => {
            nav.nextPage();
          }}
          disabled={nav.page === nav.totalPages || !nav.isNextActive}
        >
          Next
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default PageNav;
```

Comment: I think the cleanup function is not executed properly. try to move the cleanup code to `PageNav` back click event or as `Question` useEffect cleanup function

Comment: @Jerry thanks, I'm trying to move that to the pageNav right on the Back button's OnClick.

Comment: Just a side note: If `storeProperty` changes it should be in the depedency array.

Comment: @jcubic Thank you, I added that to the dependencies too.